# Unable to see whether a reopen request is approved after reaching daily review maximum

Tags: bug, review-queues, reopen-closed, vote-to-reopen

For ordinary items, I can see reviewers who approved or rejected them, even after daily maximum review number is reached. [example](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/12139968)

[image]

However, if the change happens to be a rollback, the only message presented is "Thank you for reviewing 20 reopen votes today; come back in XXX to continue reviewing.", which isn't very informative. [example](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/14191929)

[image]

I believe this is a bug.